# How to update user profile in django properly

Tags: django

i created a form to update a django profile, i use the default user model, when i submit the form and logout and i tried to login again, the new password is not working, but the old one is.
this is my update view :

```
def edit_profil_to_base(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('authentification')
    else:
        nom_profil_new = request.POST.get('nom_profil')
        nom_profil_old = request.user.username
        old_mdp = request.POST.get('old_mdp')  # type: object
        new_mdp = request.POST.get('new_mdp')
        final_mdp = request.POST.get('final_mdp')
        mdp = request.user.set_password(new_mdp)
        if request.user.check_password(old_mdp) and new_mdp == final_mdp:
            User.objects.filter(username=nom_profil_old).update(username=nom_profil_new, password=mdp)
        logout(request)
        return redirect('authentification')
```

the `new_mdp` and `final_mdp` are the new password and the confirmation of the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `set_password`. You can't do this via `update`, but you don't need to: you already have the actual object, `request.user`.

```
user = request.user
if user.check_password(old_mdp) and new_mdp == final_mdp:
    user.username = nom_profil_new
    user.set_password(mdp)
    user.save()
```

However, you really should be using a ModelForm for all of this.